# Android- RadioGroup setOnCheckedChangeListener() doesn't work

Tags: android, radio-group

i'm trying to do a listener for a RadioGroup. I don't know why, but the listener is never call when i check anyone of the radio buttons. I want to do a simple menu to select the language.
Thanks in advance!!

```
public class Language extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = Menu.class.getSimpleName();

private RadioButton englishButton, portugueseButton, spanishButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.language);
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    englishButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.english);
    englishButton.setChecked(true);
    portugueseButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.portuguese);
    portugueseButton.setChecked(false);
    spanishButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.spanish);
    spanishButton.setChecked(false);
    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group);

    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Get IN: setOnCheckedChangeListener");

            // find which radio button is selected
            if(checkedId == R.id.english) {
                portugueseButton.setChecked(false);
                spanishButton.setChecked(false);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: English", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if(checkedId == R.id.portuguese) {
                englishButton.setChecked(false);
                spanishButton.setChecked(false);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Portuguese", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if(checkedId == R.id.spanish){
                englishButton.setChecked(false);
                portugueseButton.setChecked(false);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Spanish", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

This is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            android:background="#670000"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/data_label"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:text="@string/Language"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/english"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#670000"
            android:text="@string/English"
            android:textSize="40dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/portuguese"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#670000"
            android:text="@string/Portuguese"
            android:textSize="40dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp">
        <RadioButton android:id="@+id/spanish"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#670000"
            android:text="@string/Spanish"
            android:textSize="40dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to declare the RadioButton(s) and check them manually! This is how you should use RadioGroup and RadioButton:

In your XML:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/A"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/B"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="B"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

In your Activity:

```
RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.group);
group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "changed");
        if(checkedId==R.id.A)
            Log.d(TAG, "A");
        else if(checkedId==R.id.B)
            Log.d(TAG, "B");
    }
});
```

If you want one of your RadioButton to be checked by default, simply add in the XML:

```
android:checked="true"
```

Or in your Activity:

```
group.check(R.id.A);
```

Comment: Thanks A.Omar! I've done what you said but i still can't enter in the listener. That's my problem!

Comment: You're welcome! Weird indeed... Is the code above all you got?

Comment: I've add my xml file in the post. Maybe the problem comes from there

Comment: Indeed the error is in your XML. You have to **remove** the `LinearLayout` around each `RadioButton`. If you want a padding or something simply add it to your `<RadioButton>` tag.